# Zoom in macOS Without losing resolution

Tags: macos, display, resolution, zoom

I have a 1920x1080 monitor, but the text is a little too small. How can I make the zoom factor larger without losing resolution, like in Windows?

[image]

Comment: That IS how you do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are making 'virtual pixels' that are larger than the screen's native resolution, then they will inevitably be less sharp.

There is an essential difference in how Windows and MacOS render text: Windows employs a 'nearest pixel' approach, which can be sharper but is less accurate; MacOS keeps the exact dimensions, which therefore has to be represented using aliasing for 'sub-pixel' fractions. This can appear blurry on displays with a density below 110ppi.

MacOS is designed for hi-density displays. If your 1080p display is 24", then the pixel density is c. 92ppi. A 27" display is 82ppi. Mac Retina displays are around 220ppi.